# Change number of GPUs when deploy

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have a fine-tuned Inception v3 on a 2-GPU machine.
Now I am trying to run the trained model on another machine with 1 GPU, but I got an error like this:

> Cannot assign a device to node 'tower_1/gradients/tower_1/conv0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:1' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0

It seems that the model wants a 2-GPU environment like the one it was trained on. Can I convert this model so that it uses only 1 GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two things and it worked.

1. Turn on `allow_soft_placement` option in Session:

   ```
   config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
   sess = tf.Session(config=config)
   ```
2. Rename model file name from `model.ckpt-50000.data-00000-of-00001` to `model.ckpt-50000`